# CentOS Linux EXT4 strange behaviour with Java

Tags: java, linux, centos7, unzip, ext4

I have java application (Java 8u60) that runs on CentOS 7 Linux with NVMe SSD 950GB
It's downloads zip file without about 1.5m small files (7.5gb unziped), unzip and then deletes all the unziped data and downloads same zip again and tries to unzip it again, at some stage I got an exception saying o more free space on disk.
But, when I'm checking the disk space I see that there's lots of free disk space,  (about 600GB), while needed (7.5GB).

What could be possible issue here ?

Thanks

Comment: You should check the number of available inodes of the file system. May be necessary to tune the options somehow. It's more a linux question. You may check to download the file without java, unzip, delete all unzipped files and unzip again. Should be a similar behavior.

Comment: Running as a user with a disk space quota?

Comment: Checked the inodes status, also not coming to the limits. And running user have no quota. Thanks

Comment: So you should show the complete exception/stacktrace here and the code.

Comment: Well, from the dmesg I see  :  EXT4-fs warning (device dm-0): ext4_dx_add_entry:2016: Directory index full!